# Create a certificate file in PKCS#8 format with DER encoding

Tags: certificate, azure-ad-b2c, saml, der, pkcs#8

I need to create a certificate file, that should be in `PKCS#8 format with DER encoding`. I will use this certificate for encrypting/decrypting the SAML Assertions in AD B2C.

I have tried using the `OpenSSL commands`, but unable to achieve it.

Can someone please provide any steps or references to create the certificate file? I am using windows environment.

Comment: The PKCS#8 format is for private keys, it doesn't support whole certificates.

Answer (score 0):

For B2C IEF Policy keys, you can export a certificate file as .pfx and upload the same on the portal.
You can check the doc here for the details:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/connect-with-saml-service-providers#11-prepare-a-self-signed-certificate

Also you can use PowerShell to create and export the .pfx:

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate `
    -KeyExportPolicy Exportable `
    -Subject "CN=yourappname.yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com" `
    -KeyAlgorithm RSA `
    -KeyLength 2048 `
    -KeyUsage DigitalSignature `
    -NotAfter (Get-Date).AddMonths(12) `
    -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\CurrentUser\My"

$pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "1234" -Force -AsPlainText
$thumbprint = (Get-ChildItem -Path cert:\CurrentUser\My\ | Where-Object{$_.Subject -eq "CN=yourappname.yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com"}).Thumbprint
$cert = "cert:\CurrentUser\My\$thumbprint"  
Get-ChildItem -Path cert:\CurrentUser\My\$thumbprint | Export-PfxCertificate -FilePath C:\temp\B2CCert.pfx -Password $pwd
```

I already tried this in the lab and this PowerShell script would help you in exporting the newly created Self-Signed Certificate in .pfx format in the location "*C:\temp\B2CCert.pfx*".

You can just use the .pfx format certificate that got created above.

Do let us know if this works.